# RAISERROR doesn't return correct error message using DB Express on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe2, delphi-10.1-berlin, dbexpress

I am running my application which is developed in Delphi 10.1 berlin Update 2 on windows 10 and it is accessing the Database through network (I am using SQL Server 2016 and it is installed on different machine), when stored procedure raises error using

```
`raiseerror(msg,16,1)`
```

application gets following message:

```
`SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 50000`
```

but the message doesn't contain error string. If I run same query on SQL Management Studio, I get below error.

```
SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 50000
MSG
```

I tried to run the same on windows 7 and windows Server 2012 R2 with same configuration, this time it give desired error message containing error string.
I am using dbexpress for handling queries in the application. (NOTE If I replace the implementation from dbexpress to BDE it is working fine in windows 10).

I tried to copy following .dll files of dbexpress and also dbxdrivers.ini file at the location where .exe is present

```
Borland.Data.DBXMSSQLDriver.dll
dbxadapter.dll
dbxasa.dll
dbxase.dll
dbxdb2.dll
dbxfb.dll
dbxinf.dll
dbxint.dll
dbxmss.dll
dbxmss9.dll
dbxmys.dll
dbxora.dll
Midas.dll
```

This looks like machine specific issue. Machines having windows 10 but don't have Delphi 10.1 berlin Update 2 installed, we are using these machines as Client machine where we install the application.

Also we observed these issues on application developed using Delphi XE2. So it doesn't seems to be Delphi Issue.

NOTE: Windows 10 client machines having Delphi and SQL server installed, this issue doesn't occur even with dbExpress.

Can someone please help me with this situation? Do I need copy any specify assembly files along with the package?